# Wordpress Order Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

We have a custom taxonomy called Byline that is created via More Taxonomies Plugin.

The Problem is after we save the post the Byline in case of multiple byline example (  C. Reporter, B. Reporter, A. Reporter ) 
it became (A Reporter, B Reporter, C Reporter) which we have issues with the order of names.

I check the wp_term_relationships and I found the field term_order but it wasn't being populated and even 
if i save the taxonomy one by one it's automatically sorted by term_taxonomy_id.

I use the function get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'byline', '', ', ', '' ); in calling the taxonomy.

Is there a way i can populate the term_order during post or update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

term_order is currently only used by galleries and afaik there are no plans to extend on this.

There is an entry in the trac, with [example code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9547#comment:7) on how to use it for taxonomies.